# val() of jquery sometimes not working for select element on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Just check the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function s() {
    supplier = jQuery('#sup').val();
    status = jQuery('#sta').val();
    alert('Supplier:'+supplier+'#Status:'+status); 
 }
</script>

       <select id="sup">
            <option value="empty">Supplier</option>
            <option value="1">supplier1</option>
            <option value="2">supplier2</option>
        </select>

        <select id="sta">
            <option value="empty">Status</option>
            <option value="1">status1</option>
            <option value="2">status2</option>

        </select>

        <button type="button" onclick='s()'>Show</button>
```

When I click the show-button, I am getting the value of status in FF .
But in ie, alert shows that the status contain empty-string.

Note that the supplier and status has the same structure.
The value of supplier is getting correctly in both browser.

Comment: always define var before variable declaration

Comment: Version 1.2.6 of jQuery is **very** old. And yes, your variables should be declared with `var`.

Comment: You're aware you're using a nearly 4-year old version of jQuery. Right?

Comment: @Ponity&Jamiec: In my application, I am using latest version of jquery. I prepared a simple code from my application to demo the issue.

Comment: @sandeep that is not needed , if you declared without var , it will be a global variable

Comment: @sandeep I added 'var' before variables. Now It is working fine. But In JavaScript, No need to declare a variable, right?

Comment: @HabeebPerwad Yes and no.  You aren't _required_ to declare a variable with `var`, but if you don't, it's declared as a global variable.

Comment: i dont said its problem  but its opmised technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's broken because you are using the global `status` variable - which should be used for setting status bar messages.  You need to put: `var status`
in your function `s`, not `status` or just use a different variable name.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HPR3w/2/ with the change made.  I've tested it in IE9 and it works now.

Comment: Great! I changed the variable name 'status' to 'status_'. Now it is working fine withoud adding 'var' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

try out:

```
function s() {
   var supplier = jQuery('#sup').val();
    var status = jQuery('#sta').val();
    alert('Supplier:'+supplier+'#Status:'+status); 
 }
```

One **Must** declare local variable with keyword var.

Comment: @Habeeb : Please read complete sentence, In javascript if you have to declare a local variable, you MUST declare it with keyword 'var' otherwise it will no longer be local it will become global variable automatically.

Comment: Sorry for that comment. Anyway here problem was I used a keyword. This is not an issue of local-global scope.